# how to iterate over the database table in c# mvc5?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I am developing one application using linq,api,ef. I stucked in a point where i have some tricky requirement. I have to iterate through table. Below is my database table.

```
  ID  PID PrID LID  Visibility
    80  50  0   1   VISIBLE
    81  50  0   1   HIDDEN
    82  50  81  2   HIDDEN
    84  50  82  3   HIDDEN
    85  50  82  3   VISIBLE
    89  50  82  3   VISIBLE
    92  50  82  3   VISIBLE
    93  50  81  2   VISIBLE
    118 50  82  3   VISIBLE
    125 50  82  3   VISIBLE
   2237 50  82  3   VISIBLE
   2238 50  82  3   VISIBLE
   2241 50  80  2   VISIBLE
   2242 50  80  2   HIDDEN
  2243 50  2241 3   VISIBLE
  2244 50  2241 3   HIDDEN
  2245 50  2242 3   VISIBLE
```

In the above table when PrID is 0 means furthur it wont have any parents. Current row itself is parent. 
Whenever i itrate through each row of the the above table. I want to make check weather its parents visibility is VISIBLE or HIDDEN. 
for example,
When i iterate through 3rd row, PrID is 81. Again 81's PrID is 0 so Hidden
When i iterate through 4th row ,PrID is 82. Again 82's PID is 81 which in turn 81's parent is is 0 that is Hidden and so on.

when i iterate through 5th row, PrID is 82 . Again 82's PID is 81 which in turn 81's parent is is 0 that is Hidden and so on.

When i iterate trough 8th row, PrID is 81. Again 81's PrID is 0 so Hidden

Finally i should have a list with only Visible rows.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get(int projectsId)
{
  List<NCT_Process> abc = new List<NCT_Process>();
                    abc = (from c in entityObject.NCT_Process where c.projectId == projectsId select c).ToList();
                    var visibles = abc.Where(x => IsVisible(x)).ToList();
//other code
}

 public static bool IsVisible(NCT_Process tableItem)
        {
            if (tableItem.parentId == 0)
                return tableItem.visibility;
            else
            {
                var parent = table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == tableItem.parentId);
                return IsVisible(parent);
            }
        }
```

One level up i can go and check whether PrID is visible or not. for example, In 5 th row  PrID is 82. Again 82's PID is 81 which in turn 81's parent is is 0. 
We need to check 3 levels. May I get some help to get logic here? I am trying to hard to get logic. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive function might be good for this situation..

```
    public static bool IsVisible(TableItem tableItem)
    {
        if (tableItem.PrID == 0)
            return tableItem.Visibility;
        else
        {
            var parent = table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == tableItem.PrID);
            return IsVisible(parent);
        }

    }

    static List<TableItem> table = new List<TableItem>();
    var visibles = table.Where(x => IsVisible(x)).ToList();
```

**Update** give second paramater table as Enumarable

```
       public static string IsVisible(TableItem tableItem, IEnumerable<TableItem> table)
    {
        if (tableItem.PrID == 0 || tableItem.Visibility.Equals("HIDDEN"))
            return tableItem.Visibility;
        else
        {
            var parent = table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == tableItem.PrID);
            return IsVisible(parent, table);
        }

    }

   var visibles = table.Where(x => IsVisible(x, 
               table.AsEnumerable()).Equals("VISIBLE")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. So no need to iterate through each item right?

Comment: I have ilttle doubt. I posted what i tried. Inside IsVisible method how can i get table?

Comment: in your case `var visibles = abc.Where(x => IsVisible(x, abc.AsEnumerable())).ToList();`

Comment: In the above example My result should return 3 rows(80,2241,2243). I am trying to implement recursive but i got 17 rows of data

Comment: you should not get 17 rows but am i understand wrong how about 2245 : 2245-> 2242->80 Visible=true

Comment: for example 80 Prid is 0 and it is visible so it should be returned. Next 2241's prid is 80 and 80s prid is 0 and it is visible so it should be returned and same as for 2243.

Comment: why 2245 should not be return visible for your example

Comment: for others for example 118 prid is 82. 82s parentid 81. 81s parentid is 0 and it is hidden and it should not be returned.

Comment: sorry you are correct. 2245 should not be returned. So only two rows should be returned in the above example right?

Comment: 80, 2241, 2242, 2243, 2244, 2245 should return visible total 6 rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142495/discussion-between-caner-and-niranjan-godbole).

Comment: 2245-2242   2242-80-hidden so should not return 2242-80-hidden. so 2245 and 2242 should not be returned. Only 80,2241,2243 should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one

```
   public testTable getParent(testTable item){
        var parent=item;
        while(true){
        if(parent.PrID ==0)
        break;
        parent=dbo.testTables.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id==parent.PrID)
        }
        return parent;
    }
    yourList.ToList().Select(item =>new{
        isParentVisible=getParent(item).Visibility

    })
```

Comment: Thanks. But it will check one level up right? if i have to check multiple levels then it is not correct right?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole it will check until PrID ==0 mean uppermost parent.That's what you want right?